# How to align image with text?

Tags: image, text, alignment

I want to align a brand image with the product title but I don’t know how in php..

This is my code:

```
<div class="product-name">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_attributes_placeholder'); //Placeholder for brands ?>
    <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')?></h1>
</div>
```

Image http://postimage.org/image/n0md49tqp/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image in the same div as the product name and set display: inline;
Also set clear: both in case you have a float in there.

```
.product-name{
  display:inline;
  clear: both;
}
```

If that does not work you might want to try to set both elements to float: left;